# How to disable Wireless Administration for Belkin N150 Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point, administration

I just discovered that although Remote Administration is disabled, I can still access And make changes to the router wirelessly! This is bad!

I have already set up an admin password, but I want it to be like my Linksys router - unable to access it unless I am physically wired directly to it using an ethernet cable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hoping to completely disable wireless connectivity or just wireless administration?  Here is a link to the router manual.  It discusses the former in a few easy steps... the latter may be more difficult.
ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/WNR1000v2_UM_16SEP2009.pdf

Specifically:
Log Into Router
Select Wireless Settings under Advanced in the main menu.

The available settings in this screen are:

• Enable Wireless Router Radio. If you disable the wireless router radio, wireless devices 
cannot connect to the WNR1000v2 router. If you will not be using your wireless network 
for a period of time, you can clear this check box and disable all wireless connectivity.

• Enable SSID Broadcast. Clear this check box to disable broadcast of the SSID, so that 
only devices that know the correct SSID can connect. Disabling SSID broadcast nullifies 
the wireless network discovery feature of some products such as Windows XP.
...

Comment: Could you explain how to do it here, as opposed to just linking the manual? Just hit "edit" on your post

Comment: just the wireless administration. I only use the router as a wireless router. I just don't want people able to log in wirelessly and make changes.

Comment: Also, I have to keep the router discoverable so that people can get internet wirelessly who are on my network. I just don't want them to be able to get to the administration panel without being wired by an ethernet cable.

For example, they go to 192.168.2.1 and the page times out (like would happen if you went to any wrong IP to access a router)

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  I did a search on the Netgear forums and it seems that the common response is "No, that can not be done".  It looks like you will have to load custom firmware to have any chance at all.  Here is an older SuperUser link regarding a similar issue:

http://superuser.com/questions/152461/netgear-routers-dont-allow-you-to-disable-wireless-admin

Comment: Sorry... do you have the Belkin or Netgear?  Couple routers go by similar model numbers

Comment: I have a Belkin router

Comment: From everything I have read, Belkin has not incorporated that feature.  And, unfortunately, third party firmware (tomato, dd-wrt) does not support the model you are using.  

I think the best you can hope for is a secure password and safe environment.  Make sure you are using WPA2 with a long, alpha-numeric password.  Turn off UPnP and use HTTPS access if possible.  By the time someone hacks a 14 character password, you will have moved on to a router that can control wireless access.

Comment: chose you as best answer since although it was not helpful, you were the best of all the 1 comments. lol

Comment: Enabling SSID broadcast does not help. It only stop the WAP from broadcasting its availability. It still broadcasts the SSID though when actually communicating via wireless. More of less telling someone not to mention his/her name and then starting a conversation with them with "Hey $name, did you know that..."

Answer (score 0):

> I just discovered that although Remote Administration is disabled, I can
>   still access And make changes to the router wirelessly!

Yes, why shouldn;t you be able to? Both local wired and local wireless should work.

What should be disabled is administration from the WAN port. (The side facing the Internet).